# how to get corresponding location of time zones

Tags: c, linux

I have a requirement where i need to change the time zone of the system according to the time zone specified inside particular file,if the time zone specified inside file is "PDT",i do not find the "PDT" in /usr/share/zoneinfo rather it is named as "PST8PDT". Is there any file where i could grep and get this info.
Note: Timezone specified inside file can be anything.

I need to set the TZ variable as the time zone specified in the file which requires to be as it is under /usr/share/zoneinfo dir.

Comment: Timezone names are ambiguous by themselves.  Example: `IST` is Indian/Irish/Israel Standard Time.  What do you want to do with one of these timezones.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)

Comment: I need to set the TZ environment variable to set the time zone of the system to the time zone specified in the file,so i need to specify as it is under /usr/share/zoneinfo dir.

Comment: So if the timezone specified in the file is `IST`, how do you expect to choose the correct zoneinfo (unambiguous) timezone?

Comment: IST can be set as Asia/Kolkata, i need this info only.This is what i want i need to know is there any file that says these things (or) how do i solve this?

Comment: Where does the file come from - e.g. can things be changed so that the file uses the same (unambigious) time zone names as Linux?

Comment: This is a debugging file transferred from a n/wing device,they print the output of date command inside it, i think it cannot be print so. is there any command that displays it more unambiguously.

Answer (score 1):

3-letter timezone names are ambiguous by themselves. Example: `IST` is Indian/Irish/Israel Standard Time. There is no "standard" mapping you can download because such a mapping cannot exist for the general case.

YOU will need to create a mapping table from the 3-letter timezones to the standard timezone names in zoneinfo.

To do this you must examine your input files to determine the **complete** set of 3-letter timezone abbreviations that occur *within your input data*.  You have to do this regardless of whether or not any of the input timezone abbreviations may be ambiguous.

Then, if any of those are ambiguous, then YOU have to decide, for each ambiguous abbreviation, which zonenifo timezone it refers to.  So, for example, in your table the line for `IST` would point to the zoneinfo name for `Asia/Kolkata`.

There is no shortcut here.  You must create and maintain the mapping, and you must resolve ambiguities.

Comment: Hi Jim, Sun Sep 29 00:32:24 IST 2014 this is sample output of date command where it says generically IST as the time zone. Similarly is there any command that shows it more specific like Asia/Kolkata...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's really a *correct* answer but still, try using `zdump` tool (a part of `glibc`) that can print the date in the given timezone. Even if there are multiple matches, like with `IST` in comments above, you can find them all with the code like the following:

```
$ find /usr/share/zoneinfo -type f | while read zf ; do zdump $zf ; done | grep ' IST$'
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Europe/Dublin  Sun Sep 28 19:42:38 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Eire  Sun Sep 28 19:42:38 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Asia/Kolkata  Mon Sep 29 00:12:38 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Asia/Calcutta  Mon Sep 29 00:12:38 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Asia/Colombo  Mon Sep 29 00:12:38 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Dublin  Sun Sep 28 19:42:39 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Eire  Sun Sep 28 19:42:39 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata  Mon Sep 29 00:12:39 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta  Mon Sep 29 00:12:39 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Colombo  Mon Sep 29 00:12:39 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Europe/Dublin  Sun Sep 28 19:42:14 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Eire  Sun Sep 28 19:42:14 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Asia/Kolkata  Mon Sep 29 00:12:14 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Asia/Calcutta  Mon Sep 29 00:12:14 2014 IST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Asia/Colombo  Mon Sep 29 00:12:14 2014 IST
```

For `PDT` I get 39 matches.

If you found the file you need (may need to use some kind of heuristics here to find the one you really need), set the `TZ` variable to the corresponding name.

Comment: Sun Sep 29 00:32:24 IST 2014 this is sample output of date command where it says generically IST as the time zone. Similarly is there any command that shows it more specific like Asia/Kolkata...

Comment: @user2972122: This is a OS question rather than a programming question, but `cat /etc/timezone` might work for you.

Comment: I don't think there is such a command. Zone definition files don't contain any human-readable names. For me, the only way to get `Asia/Kolkata` is to iterate through all the files (like my `while` loop in the answer does) and check all of them.